# Mongoose (Typescript): Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Defined mongoose model with typescript interface like this:

```
import { Schema, model, Document } from 'mongoose';

export interface IUserInfo extends Document {
  userId: string;
  email: string;
}

const UserInfoSchema:Schema = new Schema<IUserInfo>({
  userId: { type: String, unique: true },
  email: String
}, { timestamps: true });

export const UserInfoModel = model<IUserInfo>('userInfo', UserInfoSchema);
```

Using `UserInfoModel` to get email by userId with mongoose method like this:

```
const user: IUserInfo = await UserInfoModel.findOne({ userId: req.query.userId });
```

getting this error on `userId`:

```
Type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[]' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'Condition<string>'.
    Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

166     const user: IUserInfo = await UserInfoModel.findOne({ userId: req.query.usreId });
                                                       ~~~~~~

  src/models/userInfo.ts:4:3
    4   userId: string;
        ~~~~~~
    The expected type comes from property 'userId' which is declared here on type 'FilterQuery<IUserInfo>'
```

I can't figure out what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: The code you provided works fine. Show the full error stack. Or give a minimal, reproducible example

Comment: @slideshowp2 updated error stack

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is `findOne` [expects](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/e4ab2db/index.d.ts#L735) type `FilterQuery<IUserInfo>` here. The type `FilterQuery` has pretty [complex](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/blob/e4ab2db/index.d.ts#L2364-L2375) structure. But essentially boils down in your case to the fact that it expects an object where `userId` field must have type `string`.

`express` uses for parsing query string [`qs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) library. Where the result (`req.query`) of parsing query string is [typed](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/a86c0f6/types/qs/index.d.ts#L57) as follows:

```ts
interface ParsedQs { [key: string]: undefined | string | string[] | ParsedQs | ParsedQs[] }
```

As you may notice while the consuming function `findOne` expects only a `string`, `req.query.userId` can provide a wide range of possible result types.

From typescript's perspective that's a red flag. Imaging we're strongly expecting a string and going to `lowerCase` it right away but receiving an array of strings instead:

```ts
function lowerCase(str: string) {
    return str.toLowerCase() // totally type safe operation assuming input type
}

const stringOrArr: string | string[] = []

lowerCase(stringOrArr) // throws an error
```

So to feed the `findOne` your `req.query.userId` you have to [narrow](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html) it's type to the acceptable by the consuming function.

- you can take responsibility and just [type assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) it

```ts
const user: IUserInfo = 
    await UserInfoModel.findOne({ userId: req.query.userId as string });
```

- or take a longer route and actually narrow it using [assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions) for example:

```ts
function assertString(str: unknown): asserts str is string {
    if (typeof query.userId !== 'string') throw new Error('Must be a string')
}

assertString(req.query.userId);

const user: IUserInfo = 
    await UserInfoModel.findOne({ userId: req.query.userId }); // no error now
```

Comment: hey was working around and trying something & this worked: `findOne(req.query)`. I'm not sure this is a good idea but thanks for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution

```js
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  last: string;
}

export class PersonDoc extends mongoose.Document implements Person {}

export type PersonModel = mongoose.Model<PersonDoc>;

const personSchema = new mongoose.Schema<PersonDoc, PersonModel, Person>({
  name: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String, required: true },
  last: { type: mongoose.SchemaTypes.String, required: true },
})
```

at yow schema definition use them mongoose.SchemaTypes, instead of the normal types use usually use.